# Lightning Component - Input Params and APEX

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, aura-attribute

I am just starting to take a stab at Lightning and I have been struggling all day on something I hope is actually super simple. I want to take input from a user, click submit, and save the data.

What I have so far (and to my understanding is the correct path) is a Lightning App that calls my component. My component calls the controller, and my controller calls Apex. The params are not being passed to the Real_Estate__c object. The object is being inserted but will  null values. What am I doing wrong?

JS Controller:

```
({
"newHome" : function(cmp) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.newHomeAPEX");
    action.setParams({ "name" : cmp.get("v.houseNameInput"), "address" : cmp.get("v.houseAddressInput") });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('it worked!');
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert('incomplete');
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}        
})
```

APEX:

```
public class RealEstateClass {
@AuraEnabled
public static String newHomeAPEX(String name, String address){
    system.debug('values:: ' + name);
    Real_Estate__c re = new Real_Estate__c(Name = name, Street_Address__c = address);
    insert re;
    system.debug('re: ' + re);
    return ('Hello from the server, ' + name);
}
}
```

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component controller="RealEstateClass" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >    
    Street Address: <ui:inputText class="form-control" aura:id="houseAddressInput" />
    Home Name: <ui:inputText class="form-control" aura:id="houseNameInput" />
    <ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.newHome}" class="btn" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Troubleshooting Lightning is hard. console.log(); is your friend. It's kind of like a system.debug(); statement but for javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going about it the way you are, you'd want to use Component#find and then Component#get to get the value:

```
action.setParams({ 
    "name" : cmp.find("houseNameInput").get("v.value"), 
    "address" : cmp.find("houseAddressInput").get("v.value") });
```

You use Component#find to get a component by `aura:id`, and then Component#get to get the value from the component.

---

As an alternative to this method, you can use two-way data binding:

```
<aura:component controller="RealEstateClass" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="streetAddress" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="homeName" type="String" />

    Street Address: <ui:inputText value="{!v.streetAddress}" class="form-control" aura:id="houseAddressInput" />
    Home Name: <ui:inputText value="{!v.homeName}" class="form-control" aura:id="houseNameInput" />
    <ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.newHome}" class="btn" />
</aura:component>
```

Which then allows you to call Component#get directly:

```
action.setParams({ 
    "name" : cmp.get("v.homeName"), 
    "address" : cmp.get("v.streetAddress") });
```

Comment: thank you! I am struggling with this change over to lightning big time :(  Your snippet worked great!